# Third Text layer in a function is overlapping in Jetpack Compose- Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was trying to build basic app with jetpack compose.
I tried this:

```
@Composable
fun thisWillAppearInView(){
    Text(text = "Hello")
    Text(text = "\nLarger font")
}
```

this worked completely fine.[image: First :]

But when I tried to use the third `Text` Function, the preview started getting overlapped.
The code was like this:

```
@Composable
fun thisWillAppearInView(){
    Text(text = "\nHello")
    Text(text = "\nLarger font")
    Text(text = "Smaller font")
}
```

[image: Second:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun thisWillAppearInView(){
    Text(text = "Hello")
    Text(text = "\nLarger font")
}
```

The reason this looks like working because you are creating a Composable that has height as 2 times of your font height because you have 2 lines due to
`Text(text = "\nLarger font")` while leaving space above. Actually these 2 `Text`s are overlapping each other. If you change background of second `Text` it will be clear.

If you wish to place Composables one after another vertically you should use [Column](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#standard-layouts) Composable.

```
@Composable
fun thisWillAppearInView(){
   Column{
    Text(text = "Hello")
    Text(text = "Larger font")
    Text(text = "Smaller font")
   }
}
```